# Manually bind to parent view or controller

Tags: ember.js

How can you manually (in the `.js` file, not `.hbs`) connect bindings from a component to the parent view's controller?

Per the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Binding.html), it seems you should be able to bind a component property to the parent view's controller property. I know that the method I am about to describe used to work (around Ember v1.5).

```
var binding = Ember.Binding.from('inputValue').to('parentView.controller.outputValue');
binding.connect(this);
```

But now, `parentView` and `controller` don't exist. They seem to have been renamed to `_parentView` and `_controller` which suggests to me that it is not a "blessed" way of binding values from a component to it's parent controller.

So does anyone know if there is a way to do that, other than gumming up your `.hbs` helpers with tons of ugly code?

```
{{component-helper ComponentVar1=ContollerVar1 ComponentVar2=ContollerVar2 ComponentVar3=ContollerVar3}}

// vs.

{{component-helper}}
```

Personally, I only need values to go one way (as shown when I try to hook things up manually using `Ember.Binding`). So doing it through the helper in an `.hbs` file is not only uglier, but also unnecessarily creates two-way bindings (I think).

Answer (score 0):

After translating my component into a view instead, I realized that this is probably the "blessed" way to do these kinds of bindings.

So, yes, it is *possible* to use the underscore version of `_parentView` and `_controller`, but it is probably *better* to translate your component into a view instead, where `parentView` and `component` are still accessible.

The Ember team is pretty good about making best practices feel right and everything else feel wrong.

I guess anyone who finds this question and needs clarification, an `Ember.Component` is supposed to be modular. You should be able to pick it up from one project and drop it into another and have it all work. So manually creating bindings based on things you just happen to be using in a given project are kind of wrong.

Switching to a view with a defined template implies that you are at the mercy of the controller anyhow, so seems legit.